# What is the difference between affix, suffix, prefix and an ending?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

I know that the four words mean that a few characters are attached to a word to form a new word that has a new meaning.

I don't know the actual difference between the four words: **affix**, **suffix**, **prefix** and an **ending**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Prefix:** a chunk of characters that is placed in the beginning of a word to change its meaning or part of speech

> Desirable -> **Un**desirable

**Suffix or ending (or even postfix):** a chunk of characters that is placed in the ending of a word to change its meaning or part of speech

> Change -> Change**able**

**Affix:** any chunk that is placed in a word to change its meaning or part of speech (prefixes or suffixes)

*Note:* Some suffixes (and I believe some prefixes too) can omit characters of the words they are changing (it depends on the word)

> Desire -> Desir**able**

Some can even change characters in the words they are changing (it depends on the word)

> Likely -> Likeli**hood** (in this case we have a change in the part of speech - an adjective becomes a noun)

Comment: The word can also change the letters in the prefix, for example when you add **sub** to **fix** you get **suffix**, and **ad** to **fix** you get **affix**.